# Put file in folder instead of download

Tags: php, html, download, directory, converters

I don't know if this is even possible. I have a little website on a server where I can't install any plugins (such as imagemagick). I need to convert a PDF-file to JPG. I have found a solution where the file is sent to convertapi.com and then the user downloads the file. I perfect solution is where after converting the file it goes directly into a folder.

The code I use to convert the file:

```
<form action="https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/pdf/to/jpg?Secret=kTErGjVONEYDoaLp&download=attachment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="File" />
   <input type="hidden" name="ImageResolutionH" value="199" />
   <input type="hidden" name="ImageResolutionV" value="222" />
   <input type="hidden" name="JpgType" value="jpeggray" />
   <input type="hidden" name="JpgQuality" value="50" />
   <input type="submit" value="Convert file"/>
</form>
```

The code I use to upload the file:

```
    <?php
       if(isset($_FILES['File'])){
          $file_name = $_FILES['File']['name'];
          $file_size =$_FILES['File']['size'];
          $file_tmp =$_FILES['File']['tmp_name'];
          $file_type=$_FILES['File']['type'];
          //$file_ext=strtolower(  end( explode('.',$file_name) ) );

          $File=explode('.',$file_name);     
          $b = end($File);    
          $file_ext=strtolower( $b );

          $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png", "pdf", "txt", "PDF", "Pdf", "PDF", "Pdf");

          $errors= array();
          if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
             $errors[]="<br><h4><b>Du kan kun upload'e jpeg-, jpg-, png-, pdf- og txt-filer. Hvis du har brug for at upload'e en anden type fil, kan du kontakte mig.</b></h4>";
          }

          if($file_size > 2097152){
             $errors[]='<br><h4><b>Filen kan maks. være 2 MB stor. Hvis du har brug for at upload\'e en større fil, kan du kontakte mig</b></h4>';
          }

          if(empty($errors)==true){
             move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"documents/thumb/".$file_name);
             echo "<br><h4><b>Filen blev upload'et</b></h4>";
          }else{
             print_r($errors);
          }
       }?>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="a" />
                    <input type="submit"/>
                </form><br>
```

Can I clash these together so after conversion the file goes to a specific folder.
Note that I'm a beginner so please explain everything very detailed. :)

Comment: Is it just me or is your question very ambiguous?

Comment: I know it's very ambiguous. That's why I'm also questioning if it's even possible.